# Testing that a query on a unique identifier returns at most one result

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc

I am verifying the Login inputs (email & password) on a website by controlling that the password associated to the given email is in fact correct.
In the database, the email is the primary key.

Does it make sense in the java code, to test that the result of the query for a given email can be at most one? For example, by testing if there is a second result. Or is it useless because there is no way such a bug can happen once the database is correctly created?

```
if(rs.next()) {
    System.out.println("Something is wrong with the database");
    System.exit(1);
}
```

Also, can you comment on how to best close a program when such a big error occurs?

Comment: I would aim for simplicity here and just grab the first matching record. Of course you will want to handle the case that there are no matching records.

Comment: It sounds like you are storing plaintext passwords in the database: don't do that. Use an appropriate password hashing algorithm.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel yes I am indeed. Thank you for the suggestion, I will look into it. If you know of a guide or tutorial on how to do that, feel free to tell me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the email is the primary key there is no reason to see if there are more than one result for the email because as you said, primary keys are UNIQUE. So, don't bother checking for something that cannot happen.

If you want to put it in a test suite, I don't see the harm.

If you are afraid that the schema could be wrong you can write a test that confirms that email is a primary key.

However, for the record, I'd use a INT as the PRIMARY KEY and use the email as a UNIQUE key. Otherwise, you will have email's all over your system whenever you want to refer to an address. What happens when a user changes their email address? That's a pain, and there are more edge cases. What happens if you want to scramble email addresses for the dev db?

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. 
Right now I am using two tables, one that I use for the login [**email(PK)-password**],  
and another table to store the user infos 
[**userID(PK)-name-age-email(FK)**]. 
What set of tables would be best? Should I store all infos in one table and save only the password in an extra table with the userID?

Comment: Here is a simple user table that might work for you:
Hi @StefanMcl,

CREATE TABLE user ( user_id int unsigned not null auto_increment, email varchar(255), password_hash varchar(255), name varchar(255), age int unsigned, UNIQUE(email), PRIMARY KEY(user_id) );